# How to schedule a task with the Task Scheduler on Windows 7 that runs one minute later each day?

Tags: windows-7, windows-task-scheduler

How to schedule a task with the Task Scheduler on Windows 7 that runs one minute later each day?  That is on day one it runs at say 10:00 then the next day at 10:01, etc.

Comment: Wouldn't say it's possible without some very messy batch scripting. You're looking at using schtasks.exe to get the time and set the (time + 1 minute) at the end of the task that's already scheduled. I'd wager it's a lot easier to do this through code if you want to use Task Scheduler. You'll have access to date arithmetic that I don't think you'd get in a batch script and some built in task scheduling stuff. Long story short: *shrug*

Comment: Why do you need it to be one minute later each day?

Comment: @Nick I want to do an action on a website daily that is prohibited until 24 hours and a minute have elapsed since the last time it was performed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Set the scheduled task to kick off **every 1441 minutes**.

[image]

and here it is, all ready to run - every day and a minute.

[image]